# what is the correct syntax for this SQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

im making a website and have done a lot of `INSERT` statements but i also need a `SELECT`statements for this, pretty much the customers will be able to type in their `custID` in order to display their purchases.
So far my sql looks like this:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$con) {
        echo'Not connected to Server';
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db($con, 'horizonphotography')) {
        echo'DataBase Not Selected';
    }
    $custID = $_GET['custID'];

    $sql = "SELECT custID FROM `paymentPersonal`,  `paymentsPayment`, `paymentsProduct`,   `paymentsShipping` WHERE = $custID";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo 'Not Inserted';
    } else {
        echo 'Finding...';
    }
    header("refresh:1; url=admin.php");
?>
```

and i know the syntax isnt correct but i dont know what to write so it finds what the customers `custID` has ordered as it will be different. thankyou

Comment: i think u need join multiple table with single query without join never seen before

Comment: Because in your "FROM" you are linking tables without telling your program how to do it. You should learn about how to link tables

Comment: And I don't think you need 4 tables just to return custID (which sound like a primary Key). And you are not doing anything in your WHERE... You really have to learn how to make request. Everything is wrong in your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select query will be something like below for selecting particular field

```
$sql = "SELECT `coloumname1`,`coloumname2` from `tablename` where `someid`='matchingvalue'";
```

for selecting all the field sql query will be like below

```
$sql = "SELECT * from `tablename` where `someid`='matchingvalue'";
```

hope you understand this, so from next time please google first and than come here if not find the answer in google